How do I create a slider in AFrame?
I'm working on a project where I need to have a panel to control a bunch of joints for a robot. Right now I have a button on either side of the panel so that I can increase and decrease the values like that. It works perfectly fine but I feel like having a slider would make the user experience much better.
From research that I've already done I know there is no built in slier component in AFrame. How easy would it be to create a slider, or should I just stick to the buttons since they get the job done?
I've tried using a few APIs that people have already built and none of them worked for me, since they were built for older versions of AFrame. I'm debating trying to make my own but if it's going to be a massive hassle then I'll just cut my losses and stick to the buttons.
